# EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read in my expo-android

Tags: expo, react-native

> ```
> Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
>     at Object.readSync (fs.js:592:3)
>     at tryReadSync (fs.js:366:20)
>     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:403:19)
>     at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (C:\Users\thanu\Downloads\sociallydarkmodeandfollowshare\socially2\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.enter
> ```
>
> code herejs:304:17)
> at new UnableToResolveError (C:\Users\thanu\Downloads\sociallydarkmodeandfollowshare\socially2\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:290:35)
> at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\thanu\Downloads\sociallydarkmodeandfollowshare\socially2\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:168:15)
> at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\thanu\Downloads\sociallydarkmodeandfollowshare\socially2\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:353:43)
> at C:\Users\thanu\Downloads\sociallydarkmodeandfollowshare\socially2\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:271:42
> at C:\Users\thanu\Downloads\sociallydarkmodeandfollowshare\socially2\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1097:37
> at Generator.next ()

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).